# Different fetch url after deploy to github pages

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, router, github-pages

I deplyed my app to github-pages. Now my fetch cannot get data.
In localhost everything works great. 
I noticed that the url is different, in localhost url is

```
https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=1&per_page=80
```

Above url is correct
But when I open app in github-pages I get error like this

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/Favourite-Beers

'Favourite-Beer' is the name of my app.

I use create-react-app, react-router, redux and redux-thunk.

This is my function in actions

```
export const getBeers = () => dispatch => {

  dispatch(getBeersRequested());

  fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=1&per_page=80')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(getBeersDone(data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(getBeersFailed(error));
    })
}
```

I run this function in componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import BeerItem from '../components/BeerItem';
import { getBeers } from '../actions/index';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    beerList: state.beers.beers,
    isError: state.beers.isError,
    isLoading: state.beers.isLoading,
   };
};

class BeerList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      num: 20
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getBeers } = this.props;
    getBeers();
  }


  loadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
      num: this.state.num+20
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { beerList, isError, isLoading } = this.props;

    if(isError) {
      return <p className='error-info'>Error!</p>
    }

    if(isLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="spinner">
          <div className="double-bounce1"></div>
          <div className="double-bounce2"></div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ul className='beer-list'>
          {beerList.slice(0, this.state.num).map( beer => (
            <li key={beer.id}>
              <BeerItem
                beer={beer}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        {(this.state.num < beerList.length) &&
          <button className='btn-more' onClick={this.loadMore} >More</button>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Beers = connect(mapStateToProps, { getBeers })(BeerList);

BeerList.propTypes = {
  beerList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isError: PropTypes.bool,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool
};

export default Beers
```

Comment: show the fetch call

Comment: Would've been easier if you could just link your github page instead. `api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/Favourite-Beers` simply doesn't exist and there is no code in your question to indicate it's being called.

Comment: https://github.com/LukeWlodarczyk/Favourite-Beers

Comment: https://lukewlodarczyk.github.io/Favourite-Beers/

Comment: it doesn't look like you followed the gh-pages instructions properly https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages

Comment: I updated my code in repo. I added history and react-router-redux but it still doesn't work. Could you be more specific what I should change?

Comment: You might find [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544117/axios-fetching-data-from-file-not-working-after-deploying-to-github-pages) helpful.