# Axios fetching data from file not working after deploying to github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am writing a react app using Webpack and not create react app.
Here is a sample project folder structure:

```
data
    targetData.md
src
    component
        Text.js
    container
        App.js
    index.js
index.html
```

I am trying to read in the contents from `targetData.md` in the `Text.js` component but it doesn't seem to be working as I'm getting a `Request failed with status code 404` in the console after deploying to Github Pages. I've installed gh-pages, am able to deploy properly, and everything is rendering except the contents I try to read in from the file is not working using the following code:

```
axios.get('https://username.github.io/data/' + filename)
    .then( response => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
                data: response.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
    });
```

Rendering it:

```
 render() {
        return(
            <div>
                 {this.state.data? (<div className={styles.content}>{this.state.data}<div/>) : null}
            </div>
    )
}
```

It was working when I used a relative path in development mode, but when I deployed it to GitHub pages I noticed the 404 not found, so I thought if I put the domain URL it should work, but it didn't. What should the pathname be in `axios.get(????)` for it work after deploying to GitHub pages?

Answer (score 3):

GitHub displays files in their view. If you'd like to retrieve the content, you are after the raw version of the file.

1. Visit your GitHub repo and navigate to `targetData.md`.
2. On the right you see a button *Raw*.
3. Click it and the content of the file will show up.
4. Use that link in your `axios.get()` call.

[image: Screenshot of a GitHub repo]

The url will contain the raw word and will look something like this
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[your-username]/[your-application]/gh-pages/data/targetData.md`.